# Google map Entire world map Fit to screen (0 Zioom Level) - IOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

Friends,
I am trying to fit Google map fit into screen like..

[image]

But fortunately its just allow me to zoom out maximum at 2.

**What I tried **

```
    private func highLightVisitedCountry() {
     mainMapView.clear()

    let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:self.countriesToHighlight)
    geoJsonParser = GMUGeoJSONParser(data: jsonData!)
    geoJsonParser.parse()

    let style = GMUStyle(styleID: "random", stroke: UIColor.white, fill: Constants.MyColors.visited_country, width: 1, scale: 1, heading: 0, anchor: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), iconUrl: nil, title: nil, hasFill: true, hasStroke: true)

    for feature in geoJsonParser.features {
        feature.style = style
    }

    renderer = GMUGeometryRenderer(map: mainMapView, geometries: geoJsonParser.features)

    renderer.render()

    let centerLatLong = self.getLatLongOf(Country: self.mostVisitedCountry)

    mainMapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(latitude: centerLatLong[0], longitude: centerLatLong[1], zoom: 1.0)
}
```

from Android side here is code which work well..

```
            map:cameraZoom="1"
            map:liteMode="true"
```

Kindly please give some clue on this for IOS so i can put it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with `GoogleMap` or `MapKit`. For google map you can use camera position to zoom at `kGMSMinZoomLevel`.

There are code as follow for google map to reach at minimum zoom level, but not display whole map.

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: self.mapView.camera.target.latitude, longitude: self.mapView.camera.target.longitude, zoom: kGMSMinZoomLevel, bearing: self.mapView.camera.bearing, viewingAngle: self.mapView.camera.viewingAngle)
self.mapView.camera = camera
```

Second solution is, you can use `MapBox` to fix your solution which are provide full zoom to display whole world.

See following example: https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/